# I'm making a game and I want too make a function the user casting a spell but I want there too be a success chance in C#

Tags: c#

So, I want the success rate of the spell to be based on a percentage number. and if that percentage is 20% then it has a 20% chance of succeeding. I'm just kinda confused on how I would do something like that in C#. I currently have no code, If anyone could help me with that then thank you.

as of right now I have a c# list of the spells you have.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Random number generator.
/// </summary>
private Random rng = new Random();

/// <summary>
/// Determines whether a probabilistic action is successful.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="probability">
/// The probability of success as a proportion, i.e. x in the range 0.0 &lt;= x &lt; 1.0.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// True if the action is successful; otherwise False.
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
/// The probability x is not in the range 0.0 &lt;= x &lt; 1.0.
/// </exception>
private bool IsSuccessful(double probability)
{
    if (probability < 0.0 || probability >= 1.0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(probability), probability, "The probability of success must be x in the range 0.0 <= x < 1.0.");
    }

    return rng.NextDouble() < probability;
}
```

The `Random.NextDouble` method generates a random number in the specified range so, if you express the probability in that same range, e.g. 0.2 for 20%, any number less than the specified probability can be considered a success.

Note that the `Random` class actually generates a pseudo-random sequence that appears random enough for most purposes, but every number generated can be determined if you know the seed when the instance is created. That's actually good for testing purposes but, if you want something more random, then you could look to the `RandomNumberGenerator` or derived class. How you would use that depends on your .NET version.

Comment: so at the end of my code there is an error that says Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected. any ideas? and thank you for the help

Comment: @TheJolt70000, you probably put the code in the wrong place. That code contains a field declaration and a method declaration, so it should be obvious that they need to go inside a type but outside any member of that type. That's programming fundamentals that we shouldn't have to teach you here.

Comment: i apologize. your right this is not google and i should not have others write code for mec(most likely it would be fine too ask if they could help me get started). ill make sure that my next question i put on here is better and more focused.